# mod_rewrite enabled, rewrite Engine is on but file does not load without .php extention

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using Apache 2.4 httpd server running PHP 5.6

I have enabled mod_rewrite in the `httpd.conf` folder by removing the comment on:
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

I have added the .htaccess file to my server directory and also to the virtual host directory.

The server directory is in the `httpd.conf` file and looks like this:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/web"
<Directory "c:/web">
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

In my `httpd-vhosts.conf` I have the following:

```
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "c:\web"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "c:\web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:\web"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Personal.localhost
    ServerAlias Personal.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\personal\web"
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    <Directory "C:\personal\web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I know the Apache server loads the `.htaccess` file because if I add broken code to the file I get a `500 Internal Server Error` (It does this when the broken code is at the top or the bottom of the page.)

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
IndexIgnore * # prevent directory listing

Order deny,allow
Allow from *

# ------------------------------------------
# Hide the PHP extentions
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# ------------------------------------------
# This should set cache for all items
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|avi|js|css|html|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------
# Compress data
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

In the `access.log` file I can see the request but it doesn't add the `.php` extention to the end of the URL:

`DeveloperUsr - - [27/Jan/2016:15:12:44 +0200] "GET /admin/login HTTP/1.1" 404 209`

And the `error.log` file has the following:
`[Wed Jan 27 15:12:44.324658 2016] [negotiation:error] [pid 18324:tid 1084] [client ::1:50784] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: C:/Personal/web/admin/login (None could be negotiated).`

What can I do to enable the `.htaccess` or the URL rewrite. I know that the `.htaccess` file works because if I load the server to the Linux Production Environment it loads and works. I don't have access to the config files for the production environment, so I can't see what is wrong with my config files.

Comment: @anubhava there is a .htaccess in `C:\web` and in `C:\Personal\web`. The PHP file is located in `C:\personal\web`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable MultiViews if you're relying on mod_rewrite to map in this way.